# Using a variable to set the description field in a PayPal API

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm trying to set the description field using a string variable from C# codebehind.  I cannot get the buttons to work unless I hardcode the description in the Javascript embedded in the HTML code.

The goal is to build a single amount paid with a variable description.  I have the amount worked out but cannot seem to get the description field to take.  The buttons render but when clicked on I just get the error message.

It does work if I use:

```
Description: "Hard Code Info"
```

I'm new to Javascript - any help would be appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xx&currency=USD&intent=capture"></script>
<script>
  var num
  var apr
  var ssk
  const paypalButtonsComponent = paypal.Buttons({
    // optional styling for buttons
    // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/buttons-style-guide/
    style: {
      color: "gold",
      shape: "rect",
      layout: "vertical"
    },

    // set up the transaction
    createOrder: (data, actions) => {
      // pass in any options from the v2 orders create call:
      // https://developer.paypal.com/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body
      num = document.getElementById("MyAmount").textContent;
      ssk = document.getElementById("WhyDonate").textContent;
      const createOrderPayload = {
        purchase_units: [{
          description: {
            value: ssk
          },
          amount: {
            value: num
          },
        }],
        items: [{
          name: "Dues Or Donation",
          unit_amount: {
            currency_code: 'USD',
            value: num,
          },
          quantity: "1"
        }]
      };
      return actions.order.create(createOrderPayload);
    },

    // finalize the transaction
    onApprove: (data, actions) => {
      const captureOrderHandler = (details) => {
        const payerName = details.payer.name.given_name;
        document.getElementById("MyAmount").textContent = apr;
        document.getElementById('<%=ClearSession.ClientID %>').click();
      };
      return actions.order.capture().then(captureOrderHandler);
      console.log(Details);
    },

    // handle unrecoverable errors
    onError: (err) => {
      console.log('An error prevented the buyer from checking out with PayPal');
      // alert('An error prevented the buyer from checking out with PayPal');
    }
  });

  paypalButtonsComponent
    .render("#paypal-button-container")
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('PayPal Buttons failed to render');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The API can't tell the difference between a variable or a literal in the parameters. So the problem is probably that the variable doesn't have the correct value. Use `console.log(ssk)` to make sure it contains what you expect.

Comment: Thank you - tried it but ssk keeks coming up undefined, which is probably causing the error.

Comment: I don't see how that could happen immediately after `ssk = document.getElementById("WhyDonate").textContent;`. Even if the element doesn't have any content this will return an empty string, not `undefined.

Comment: I found a solution by predefining the variable

Comment: var num;
                var apr;
                let ssk = '<% = WhyDonate.Text %>';
                const paypalButtonsComponent = paypal.Buttons({

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. However, if you don't declare the variable as a local variable, and you call some other function that reassigns it, that could be a problem. Make sure you always declare variables. `let ssk = document.getElementById("WhyDonate").textContent;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actions.order.create` and `.capture` are deprecated and should not be used for any new integration; support will be sunset and removed in the future.

Instead, create and capture the order from a backend (not browser JS) -- and fetch to those routes from the JS you have.

See the [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) for details and an example. That example uses node.js for its backend but of course those backend routes can be implemented in any environment/language; whatever you're using for your server.